# Android / Google Play in-app purchase "Item unavailable in your country"

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to test the in-app purchase of a consumable item on Android, but I'm unable to do so, as the item appears as being unavailable in my country:

[image]

This only happens when I'm testing on a device connected to Android Studio (which I need to be able to do) - if I instead download the app onto the device, the consumable item appears normally, i.e. as being available.
Some details:

- I'm testing on a physical device running Android version 6.0.1
- That device is running the latest version of the Google Play application
- I'm testing with a user that has been set up both as a track tester and a license tester, and that is also currently signed in on the device
- I've made the app available in all available 177 countries and regions
- The app does not have a production release, it's only available on the closed testing track

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @MittalVarsani I did - see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution in my case was to select the app in the Google Play Console, then go to **Release > Production > Countries/regions**, and add the countries/regions there. Having the countries/regions selected in the closed/internal track only is not sufficient. It seems this is necessary *regardless of whether one actually has a production release or not* - again, in my case, I did not. It took maybe 10-20 mins after I made the update until I stopped seeing the issue.

Answer (score 7):

If you have uploaded the build from the closed track, please ensure that you have accepted the test invitation from the invited email or it will show this error.

**Step 1: Go to Release -> Testing -> Closed Testing**

[image]

**Step 2: Click on Manage Track**

**Step 3: Click on Testers tab**

[image]

**Step 4: Scroll to the bottom and you will see 2 options. Copy the link for web and open the link in your phone or browser with the test email you want to test.**

[image]

**Step 5: When you open the link you will have an option to Become A Tester. Click on that and then you are good to go.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**
Upload to the Internal Test track and make sure it has the highest version code

I was having this issue for a few days, and also tried numerous things, but to no avail.. I uploaded my app bundle to a Closed Testing track in the Play Store, which did not solve the problem. After countless other methods, I eventually tried to upload a bundle to the Internal Testing track, which immediately solved the issue and allowed me to use test cards again.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it, but unfortunately the issue persists. Can I confirm that you're not seeing the issue even when your app is being run on a device connected to Android Studio? Also, apart from the internal test track version of your app, do you also have a production version?

Comment: That is correct. I have uploaded an APK with versionCode 14 to the store, and I am running my app (debug) from Android Studio with versionCode 14. I have not signed it with my production key. I do not currently have a production version yet, only internal testing and closed testing

Comment: In that case I'm at a loss as to why it's not working for me. Thanks, at least I can add this to the list of things I've tried.

Comment: Not working for me